# dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged firing on button click if they have same values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code like this:

on.aspx page

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected="True"> 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4"> 1</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

 <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

on aspx.cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

here issue is that, when i click on button at that time DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged also firing. 
as i gone thru and found that this happening due to same value for different itemtext.

```
 <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected="True"> 3</asp:ListItem>
```

I can`t do changes in value.

Is there any luck? or what the exactly issue is?

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` fires when the selection changes. It does not take into account the values or text being the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please check DropDownList AutoPostBack Property.

if AutoPostBack is true

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a postback to the server
>   automatically occurs when the user changes the list selection.

Comment: This will make the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to not fire at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ViewState is Enabled on Web Page and add it on Page load

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        //do code here

    }
```

Comment: I don't get how Enabling `ViewState` OR using `IsPostBack` be useful in this situation. Still there is a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged` fires when the selection changes. It does not take into account the values or text being the same.

That is why it is named `SelectedIndexChanged` & not *SelecteValueChanged* OR *SelectedTextChanged*.

So if you want your `SelectedIndexChanged` event and also want that it does not fire if it has the same `Value` or `Text`. It would not be possible.

IMHO : `Value` OR `Text` should not be duplicated in a `DropDownList`. You should get rid of the duplicate values from the DataSource before binding it.